# Eloquent global scope interfering with Delete requests

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this global scope:

```
class EarmarkScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'earmarks.by_id')
            ->leftJoin('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'earmarks.location_id')
            ->select('earmarks.*', 'users.name AS by', 'locations.location')
            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

But when trying to call: `Earmark::destroy($id);` I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
>   where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `earmarks`.*, `users`.`name` as
>   `by`, `locations`.`location` from `earmarks` left join `users` on
>   `users`.`id` = `earmarks`.`by_id` left join `locations` on
>   `locations`.`id` = `earmarks`.`location_id` where `id` in (72) order
>   by `date` asc)

I realize the global scope is causing this, but having that scope saves me so, so much time on SELECT queries. How can I avoid it causing a problem with `destroy()` and other useful Laravel functions like `find()` ?

Comment: what happen if you use `Earmark::withoutGlobalScope(EarmarkScope::class)->destroy($id)`?

Comment: I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::destroy()`

Comment: if you don't mind, what laravel version did you use? anyway, [just read the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1065) it did not apply scopes for destroying things..

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.3

Comment: weird, the Model should not fire any scope at all while deleting, [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1145). How did you call the query, is it only `Earmark::destroy($id);`..? alternatively, could you do [`Earmark::withoutGlobalScope(EarmarkScope::class)->find($i‌​d)->delete()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L596) ?

Comment: Weirdly this works just fine: `Earmark::where('earmarks.id', $id)->delete();`

Comment: it works because [`Earmark::where()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L789) actually executes on a model query builder..

Comment: @daninthemix Did you find a solution to this?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it quite wrong here.

A. Set up relations on your models. There is absolutely no need for global scope here.

B. Don't use `join`s on your global scope, but use `whereIn`

```
$builder->whereIn(
    'by_id', function ($q) {
    $q->select('users.id')
        ->from('users')
        ->where('something useful...');

}
);
```